# What is the difference between “audition” and “performance”?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

> If you do a good audition/performance, you may get on the show.

Which is the right choice — *audition* or *performance*?

Comment: Not very clear sorry. This is an exam question and i have to pick one of the choices there. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: What was unclear about saying the audition is *before* the show?

Comment: To the user who suggested changing "good" with "well during a/an..." There is nothing ungrammatical about "a good audition" But writing "If you do a well during a/an..." is very wrong!

Comment: You're posting to the wrong list. You need English Language Learners.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

An audition is like a job interview. If you pass the test you get the work.

The audition is before the show; a performance is what you do.

You could say

> If you give a good performance at the audition you might get on the
>   show.

Or you could say

> If you pass the audition you could give a great performance on the
>   show.

But if this is an exam question the correct answer is **audition**.

> If you do a good **audition** you may get onto the show.

Comment: I like this answer, except that "make a good performance" sounds horrible and stilted to me (like the kind of thing a foreign speaker would say).  I would expect "give a good performance" (or "perform well").

Comment: Also, "audition" and "performance" are both nouns, so they are the same part of speech.  "Event" and "action" are not parts of speech.

Comment: If you act well, dance well, play well, sing well, do well at the audition, you may get to perform in a show. I'm not crazy about "do a good audition". If your audition goes well, you might get to perform on stage or in the movie, etc.

Comment: @Lambie my last sentence is the answer to the actual exam question, *audition or performance*, which was not about its other grammar.